# Confusion matrix missing instances

Tags: python, pyspark, confusion-matrix

I'm using PySpark to generate and validate a prediction. I have a dataframe with the correct columns, and I'm passing it to the MulticlassMetrics to get the confusion matrix. But when I check the confusion matrix it is missing most of the values (the dataframe has over 120.000 rows and the confusion matrix only has 8 or so values). Why is it losing the rest?

Edit: to clarify, I do not expect the confusion matrix to have the same size as the data set, I have two classes in my data, and I expect that the sum of the matrix instances will be the same as the number of rows in my data. The problem is that I have about 120.000 rows in my data and the confusion matrix is something like
`[[ 0, 3 ],
  [ 1, 0 ]]`

Code: I can't post the entire code here, but here is the part that matters

```
training_data = load_training_data() # Spark DataFrame
training_data, testing_data = training_data.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])

asm = VectorAssembler(inputCols=selected_columns, outputCol='features')
final_training_data = asm.transform(training_data)

rf = RandomForestClassifier(labelCol="label", impurity="entropy")
rfModel = rf.fit(final_training_data)

test_predictions = rfModel.transform(testing_data)
predictionAndLabels = test_predictions.select(['prediction', 'label'])

tp = predictionAndLabels.rdd.map(tuple)
metrics = MulticlassMetrics(tp)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Are you expecting your confusion matrix to be the same size as your dataset?

Comment: Just for reference the confusion matrix will be a square matrix whose dimensions will be equal to the number of classes in your data. So if you have 3 classes the matrix will be 3x3

Comment: I edited the question to clarify my doubt

Comment: So is the 120k rows your test set? Otherwise how did you split your data?

Comment: Yes, I used a random split of 30% for testing and 70% for training. So the 120k are the testing set.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: It's kind of hard to answer without at least some excerpt from the code. Obviously something is happening in your implementation that is not expected in the documentation. Also please see the guidelines for generating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Generally speaking SO users can't give you specific help unless you post code.

Comment: Ok, I posted an excerpt of the code that is generating the metrics, my idea is that something is happening inside the MulticlassMetrics constructor, since I've checked the tp and it has the correct amount of rows, and they're all valid.

Comment: Great! That makes this alot more clear. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good example of how to use the [`MulticlassMetrics`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-evaluation-metrics.html#multiclass-classification). In this example the data contains 150 observations that fall into one of three classes. As a result the final confusion matrix is of shape 3x3 represented as a DenseArray in a single dimension. If you walk through the example in the link and stop once you get to `metrics = MulticlassMetrics(predictionAndLabels)` you can do the following to visualize the confusion matrix.

```
In[6]: metrics = MulticlassMetrics(predictionAndLabels)
In[7]: confusion_mat = metrics.confusionMatrix()
In[8]: print(confusion_mat)
Out[8]: DenseMatrix(3, 3, [15.0, 0.0, 7.0, 0.0, 16.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 13.0], 0)
In[9]: print(confusion_mat.toArray())
Out[9]: array([[ 15.,   0.,   1.],
               [  0.,  16.,   0.],
               [ 7.,   0.,  13.]])
```

The final array is what you would interpret as the confusion matrix. Take a look at Wikipedia's entry for [Confusion Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) for more info and a nice example of a multiclass matrix.

Without more information about your data I cannot say for sure but it sounds like you have a 2x2 or a 3x3 confusion matrix and you just need to call `toArray` to better visualize it.

**Edit** (Thanks for adding your code.)

Normally when I run `RandomForestClassifier.transform(test)` I end up with a `predictedLabel` column which is the actual class of the prediction. Furthermore I don't think you should have to call `predictionAndLabels.rdd.map(tuple)`. After you select `predictedLabel`, and 'label' from `test_predictions` you should be able to go directly to the metrics. To sum up try the following:

```
predictionAndLabels = test_predictions.select(['predictedLabel', 'label'])
metrics = MulticlassMetrics(predictionAndLabels)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try it and let you know if it worked!

Comment: In Spark 2.4, this throws an attribution error when you execute the second line. `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ctx'`

Comment: @BryanButler, you are correct. I have the same error. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @HovanesGasparian I have not gotten back to this project.  Someone suggested using standard sklearn code.

Comment: @BryanButler thank you! That's what I ended up doing.